# Find the general solution to the differential equation $(x+1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = (1+x)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I'm having a problem with the following differential equation, from a [Sixth Term Examination Paper](https://www.admissionstesting.org/for-test-takers/step/about-step/) question (STEP 3 2011 Q1). The problem arises with me trying to apply a technique in an earlier part of the question to a later part.

The third part of the question (iii) asks to find a general solution to the differential equation:
$$(x+1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = (1+x)^2$$

An earlier part of the question (ii) asks to find a solution to a similar differential equation:
$$(x+1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = 0$$
Using the substitution $y = ze^{-x}$, where $z$ is some function of $x$. I managed to get this to work, and using this substitution the equation turns into

$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} - \frac{x+2}{x+1}\frac{dz}{dx} = 0$$

Which is fairly straightforward to solve using methods such as the integrating factor, as this is just a first order differential equation in $\frac{dz}{dx}$.

**However**, applying this to the third part of the question (iii) I assumed that the equation would just turn into

$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} - \frac{x+2}{x+1}\frac{dz}{dx} = (1+x)^2$$

Since the $(1+x)^2$ on the right hand side does not depend on $y$.

However, this is wrong and the $(1+x)^2$ turns into $(1+x)e^x$. I don't know if I am just missing some step and rushing to the substitution but I don't see how to get this $(1+x)e^x$ function, and [this solution from The Student Room](https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1687556#post32409387) skips over the step.

Please can you show me how the substitution results in $(1+x)e^x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x+1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = (1+x)^2$$
If you change the variable then:
$$y=ze^{-x}$$
$$y'=z'e^{-x}-ze^{-x}$$
$$y''=z''e^{-x}-2z'e^{-x}+ze^{-x}$$
So that the differential equation:
$$(x+1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = (1+x)^2$$
Becomes:
$$(x+1)(z''e^{-x}-2z'e^{-x}+ze^{-x}) + x(z'e^{-x}-ze^{-x})- ze^{-x} = (1+x)^2$$
You have to multiply the whole equation by  the exponential $e^x$ since it's not zero on the RHS this explains the presence of the exponential on RHS.
$$(x+1)(z''-2z'+z) + x(z'-z)- z =\color {red}{e^x} (1+x)^2$$
$$(x+1)z''- z'(x+2) =\color {red}{e^x} (1+x)^2$$
When you change the variable in the homogeneous equation you have on RHS:
$$(x+1)(z''e^{-x}-2z'e^{-x}+ze^{-x}) + x(z'e^{-x}-ze^{-x})- ze^{-x} = 0$$
$$e^{-x}((x+1)(z''-2z'+z) + x(z'-z)- z) = 0$$
$$(x+1)(z''-2z'+z) + x(z'-z)- z = e^x \times 0$$
$$(x+1)z''-z'(x+2) = 0$$

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise the special case that the 0 caused.

Comment: You're xelcome. Yes the exponential is just absorbed by the zero of tehe homogeneous part of the DE @Robin